# Spring AOP: is it possible to define pointcuts in imported classes or interfaces, and how?

Tags: spring, aop, pointcut

I'm trying to define a pointcut on all classes, or at least one class in an imported library in Spring. However, when I run the application, I get

```
[tomcat:launch] SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
[tomcat:launch] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.example.package [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
[tomcat:launch]         at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:301)
[tomcat:launch]         at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:207)
[tomcat:launch]         at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:193)
[tomcat:launch]         at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:182)
[tomcat:launch]         at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:163)
[tomcat:launch]         at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:210)
[tomcat:launch]         at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:264)
[tomcat:launch]         at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:296)
[tomcat:launch]         at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
[tomcat:launch]         at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
[tomcat:launch]         at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
[tomcat:launch]         at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
[tomcat:launch]         at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
[tomcat:launch]         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
```

Comment: Post the configuration and source code. That stack trace doesn't say much.

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives a good hint:

```
no match for this type name:
com.example.package [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
```

You seem to have specified a mere package name as a type name in your pointcut. Probably you wanted to write something like this instead:

- `com.example.package.MyClass` for a specific class
- `com.example.package.*` for all classes in the package
- `com.example.package..*` for all classes in the package and its subpackages